# .NET Maui adding Entitlements.plist breaks build

Tags: ios, plist, maui, applinks, code-signing-entitlements

Using Visual Studio CE 2022 17.44

Following the directions for setting up appLinks on iOS, one of the steps is to add the Entitlements.plist with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
        <array>
            <string>applinks:popupshop.azurewebsites.net</string>
            <string>applinks:*.popupshop.azurewebsites.net</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I then add the Entitlements.plist as the custom resource rules file:

[image: Project Bundle Signing Settings]

This adds this line to the project file:

```
<CodesignResourceRules>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignResourceRules>
```

Once this has been added the project no longer builds. If I remove it or replace it with:

```
<CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
```

as per someone's suggestion, the project will build again, but accessing the applink does not switch over to the app. https://popupshop.azurewebsites.net/findshop

I have the apple-app-site-association file available at https://popupshop.azurewebsites.net/apple-app-site-association and https://popupshop.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

which contains:

```
{
    applinks: {
        apps: [ ],
        details: [
            {
                appID: "75Q8SL8Q65.net.popupmobile.popupshop",
                paths: [ "/findshop/*" ]
            }
        ] 
    }
}
```

Not sure why the tag entered by Visual Studio blows up the build.
UPDATE:
the error is the following:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Failed to codesign '/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/PopUpShop.Mobile.Maui/35dcaca089e6ce3e7267432b2824427bbb34327e5d2422b0725e05c26c8d46db/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone15.3-16.1.2/PopUpShop.Mobile.Maui.app': 
Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!



bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/device-builds/iphone15.3-16.1.2/PopUpShop.Mobile.Maui.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources

        PopUpShop.Mobile.Maui   C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.1.1477\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets  2128
```

UPDATE: The VS Screen shot above is different than what i see on the Microsoft site (see below). I am missing the 'Custom Entitlements' section for some reason.

[image: visual studio project settings]

Comment: How does the build break?  What error or exception is happening?

Comment: Oops. Added the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why my visual studio is broken, but if yours is the same and you want to add Entitlements.plist, add the following to your project.csproj under the ios debug and release sections:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
....
  <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! You could mark this answer and this could help people with same questions. I also find some info [Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vs) , [Adding an Entitlements.plist breaks the iOS project](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3715).