# App Entitlements.plist in a MAUI project for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, maui

In my `.NET8` `MAUI` project, I like to use the `SecureStorage`. I read that for that, I have to create an `Entitlements.plist` in the `iOS` folder. I followed the steps from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs). I added the `Entitlements.plist` in the *Custom Entitlements*. I created the file like a normal XML and then I renamed it.

[image]

Now, the error I get is

> error : Resources rules file 'Platforms/iOS/Entitlements.plist' not found.

I looked around and I found this [post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75658021/net-maui-adding-entitlements-plist-breaks-build) and I edited the project adding

```
<PropertyGroup 
   Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
....
  <CodesignEntitlements>Platforms\iOS\Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but I continue to get the same error. Is there any particular `Build Action` to set?

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that there is no `Entitlements.plist` file under Platforms/iOS folder.

When using [Secure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) and developing on the **iOS simulator**, you should enable the **Keychain** entitlement and add a keychain access group for the application's bundle identifier.

You could add a new XML file named `Entitlements.plist` to the Platforms\iOS\ folder of your app project. Then add the following XML to the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
      <key>keychain-access-groups</key>  
      <array>  
            <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)xxx</string>  
      </array>  
</dict>  
</plist>
```

**PS**: xxx means the **Bundle Identifier** of your iOS project, you can open the `info.plist` file and copy the value.

For more details about Entitlements.plist, you can refer to [Entitlements and capabilities - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/entitlements?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs). Last but not least, there's a working example:[Secure Storage App with .NET MAUI](https://github.com/erdalkama/SecureStorageMaui/tree/main) for your reference.